# System.Net.Http - Reference added *always* shows warning triangle

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application and a class lib, C#, .NET 4.6.2

In class lib, I go to manage nuget packages and add System.Net.Http latest (4.3.3)

It succeeds, but the warning triangle is there immediately.

If I try to utilise it, it says 'unable to load System.Net.Http 4.2.0.0 (this version does not exist)

I have tried binding redirects, I've uninstalled everything, re-installed everything, restarted Visual Studio, tried diagnostic MSBUILD info

It will not work. It says it doesn't match the assembly manifest (the typical error) - but it does not point me at any mismatch. There's nothing to consolidate in the Nuget UI either.

Why is this SO hard to resolve? It's such a simple class library which makes use of HttpResponseMessage, which I'm trying to utilise from another, very simple console application.

Incredibly frustrating. What is 4.2.0.0? Why doesn't this exist in Nuget? What is the conflict? Why does it not just work as it should?

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you using? I cannot reproduce the same behavior: created a brand new solution, with a console app and a class lib (both C#, .NET 4.6.2), built it and no error or warning were displayed.

Comment: May I ask **why** you add the nuget package in the first place? Your framework has a perfectly good implementation, you don't need to add another one.

Comment: @nvoigt why does it exist on Nuget then?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel I might go ahead and start over with some new assemblies with a '2' on the end then. Perhaps this one is just borked, somehow.

Comment: @SpaceBison Because projects that **don't** target the full framework might need it. You don't.

Comment: @nvoigt I _do_ want to be able to not target the full framework in due course though. Hence using nuget. This is sort of nitpicking over something which isn't completely relevant to this problem though - regardless of where the reference comes from, I cannot seem to make use of it without FileLoadExceptions occurring.

Comment: @SpaceBison If you want to target non-full Frameworks (Core or Standard) you need to make up your mind, decide on one and then add this package. It should work. You may even have different target frameworks and include the nuget package only in those builds that need it. It just doesn't work when you add it to a project that shouldn't need it in the first place.

Comment: @nvoigt added framework version - same problem, as expected. the source of the dll isn't relevant. going to abandon the idea entirely as it's just a waste of time.

Comment: Maybe you can create test project which reproduces the problem and upload somewhere (like github)?

Comment: @Evk If I get chance later today I'll try to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package to both the console application and the class library. Also, add reference from the framework and not from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this from time to time, especially with projects that have multiple dlls ( libraries ) as part of the solution.

You are probably getting a warning about a mismatched system.net.http in the build output and that is the lib that is throwing the runtime error later.

Try:
adding  true to ALL your *.csproj files

adding the newest nuget package to THE DLL project that is having issues ( see above )

make sure that you have binding redirects in all projects that point to all the same ( highest ) version of system.net.http